# How to define groups to efficiently search for k element combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following question and I would appreciate your help. Starting from a set "L" items I want to find a specific "k" element combination that satisfies some unique conditions.

I am aware that there are C(L,k) such combinations, which can be a lot. However I have the ability to define groups of M elements and check if any of the C(M,k) combinations that can occur satisfy the conditions.

This is a single operation and I can quickly exclude a larger set of C(L,k) without checking the elements individually.

My question is, what would be the most efficient way to define the groups of M elements so that the space of C(L,k) is fully covered with the least number of groups? If I am correct the appropriate selection should lead to significant reduction in search time.

Comment: To start simplifying a little, suppose $k$ divides $M$ and $M/k$ divides $L$:
one solution is to divide $L$ in $M/k$ contiguous intervals, then compose each group of $M$ elements by taking $k$ of these intervals. You will need ${kL/M \choose k}$ groups. If $k$ does not divide $M$ or $M/k$ does not divide $L$ adapt the method to cover all $L$ elements. Anyway I am not sure this is the most efficient solution, i.e. if ${kL/M \choose k}$ is minimal. Hope that someone is able to prove it or comes up with a better solution.