# Alternative proof for ${pn \choose n}{qn \choose n} \ge {pqn \choose n}$ inequality

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4560715/573047), I saw that for $p,q,n$ positive integers the following inequality holds:

$${pn \choose n}{qn \choose n} \ge {pqn \choose n}$$

The inequality is not tight.

A simple combinatorial proof is the following: divide the interval $1, \ldots, pqn$ into $pn$ subsequent contiguous intervals of length $q$ then choose $n$ of them to form a subset of $\{1, \ldots, pqn\}$ with $qn$ elements. After this choose $n$ of these elements. Whatever is the choice of an arbitrary subset of $n$ elements of $\{1, \ldots, pqn\}$ there exists a way to cover it with $n$ of the contiguous intervals as defined above, at worst with one interval for each element.

Is there an algebraic or other way to prove the inequality?

Comment: How do you choose a combination of $n$ of them and get a subset with $qn$ elements (rather than $n$ elements?)

Comment: Also, I think the inequality is tight for $n=1$.

Comment: Equivalently, prove that $(pn)!(qn)!(pqn-n)! \ge n!(pn-n)!(qn-n)!(pqn)!$.

Comment: @AryanDugar: Indeed, if $n=1$, then the two sides are equal.  Perhaps this can be used as the base case for an induction on $n$.

Comment: @AryanDugar I have removed "combination", hope it is clearer now. Yes for $n=1$ it is an equality but the LHS grows much more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do induction on $p$.

$p=1$ is trivial.

To complete the induction step, it is enough to show the following inequality.
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{{(p+1)n \choose n}}{pn \choose n} \ge \frac{(p+1)qn \choose n}
{pqn \choose n}
\end{aligned}$$
The LHS is
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(p+1)n-i}{pn-i}=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(p+1)qn-qi}{pqn-qi}$$
The RHS is
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(p+1)qn-i}{pqn-i}$$
Since $\frac ab\ge\frac{a+c}{b+c}$ when $a>b>0$ and $c\ge0$, we see that LHS > RHS.